# Learning Curves: Should the training set size be increased incrementally or Random Selection?

Tags: machine-learning, training-data

I am trying to write a bespoke learning curve function. I was wondering how is it usually implemented. When the size of the training set is increased - Is it normally increased by adding new samples to the already existing set incrementally? Or is the training size size is selected randomly?

To give an example: Suppose the train-set size ratios are [0.2, 0.3, 0.4 ...], then when we go from 0.2 to 0.3, do we add an extra 0.1 on top of what existed before(0.2) incrementally? Or do we just get another random sample from the full set?

Answer (score 0):

do we just get another random sample from the full dataset.